# WCF custom serializer do not work

Tags: wcf, serialization

Want to replace wcf serializer with a custom one.
After googling I've found examples. But it do not work.
Here is my code:
Substitutor:

```
    internal class MySerializerSubstitutor : DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
    {
        private static readonly MySerializer _serializer = new MySerializer();
        public MySerializerSubstitutor (OperationDescription operationDescription)
            : base(operationDescription)
        {

        }

        public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(Type type, string name, string ns, IList<Type> knownTypes)
        {
            return _serializer; //NEVER CALLED
        }

        public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(Type type, XmlDictionaryString name, XmlDictionaryString ns, IList<Type> knownTypes)
        {
            return _serializer; // NEVER CALLED
        }
    }
```

Behavior which repolace serializer

```
public class MySerializerBehavior : IOperationBehavior
{
```

.......

```
public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription description, DispatchOperation dispatch)
    {
        var dcs = description.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();

        if (dcs != null)
            description.Behaviors.Remove(dcs);

        description.Behaviors.Add(new MySerializerSubstitutor(description)); //works fine
    }
```

.............

```
}
```

And host:

```
protected override void ApplyConfiguration()
{
var behavior = new MySerializerBehavior()
                foreach (var op in Description.Endpoints.SelectMany(ep => ep.Contract.Operations))
                {
                    op.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
                }
}
```

Whats wrong with this code?

Comment: Is ApplyConfiguration called? Also, you should remove the original DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior before ApplyDispatchBehavior - at that point it's possible that it has already been invoked, so it already added its runtime pieces and you won't get a chance to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem that is immediately visible is that you cannot replace a behavior from a behavior.  According to MSDN:

> All of the IOperationBehavior methods pass an OperationDescription
>   object as a parameter. This parameter is for examination only; if you
>   modify the OperationDescription object the execution behavior is
>   undefined.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.ioperationbehavior.aspx

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish, but here is an example that modifies properties of the serializer behavior.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.datacontractserializeroperationbehavior.aspx

If you need more customization than the properties provide you can try to replace the DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.  EDIT: Just make sure you add it before calling Open.  See this article for adding a new behavior http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730137.aspx