# WCF custom serialization using an endpoint behavior

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-serialization

I have a service that runs on a LAN with no clients other than the ones I create. I have been attempting to remove the default DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior and replacing it with a custom one I have written and thus far have been wildly unsuccessful. I am using C# 4.5 and run on NetTcpBindings.

I wrote the following 3 classes using protobuf-net's implementation as an example. I will only include what I consider to be the main parts of the classes. If more detail is required then I will provide it.

CustomXmlObjectSerializer : XmlObjectSerializer

CustomSerializerOperationBehavior : DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior

```
public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(Type type, string name, string ns, IList<Type> knownTypes) {
    return new CustomXmlObjectSerializer();
}

public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(Type type, XmlDictionaryString name, XmlDictionaryString ns, IList<Type> knownTypes) {
    return new CustomXmlObjectSerializer();
}
```

CustomEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior

```
private void ReplaceDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) {
    foreach (var operation in endpoint.Contract.Operations)
        ReplaceDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(operation);
}

private void ReplaceDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(OperationDescription operation) {
    for (var i = 0; i < operation.Behaviors.Count; i++) {
        if (operation.Behaviors[i] is DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior) {
            operation.Behaviors[i] = new CustomSerializerOperationBehavior(operation);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The instantiation of the service host looks like this:

```
serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ImplementationType));
var contract = typeof(ContractType);
var binding = GetBinding(configuration.Address, configuration.MaxTransferSize * 1024 * 1024);
var endpoint = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(contract, binding, configuration.Address);
endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new CustomEndpointBehavior());
serviceHost.Open();
```

The instantiation of the service client looks like this:

```
var binding = GetBinding(configuration.Address, configuration.MaxTransferSize * 1024 * 1024);
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(configuration.Address);
factory = new ChannelFactory<ContractType>(binding, endpoint);
factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new CustomEndpointBehavior());
```

When I do this I can see the CustomEndpointBehavior replacing the DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior with my CustomSerializerOperationBehavior however I never actually see the calls to create the CustomXmlObjectSerializer (and subsequent usage of it).

I have tried switching my binding from NetTcpBinding to BasicHttpBinding and have seen no change in behavior.

Does anyone have any insight as to why, even after observing each operation's default DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior being replaced with the CustomSerializerOperationBehavior I don't actually see a change in the serialization behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF custom serializer do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456816/wcf-custom-serializer-do-not-work)